# Premature completion of publisher in flatMap in Combine

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have this minimal example:

```
import UIKit
import Combine

var values = [1,2,3,4,5]

var cancel = values.publisher
    .delay(for: 0.1, scheduler: DispatchQueue.global())
    .print()
    .flatMap() { i in
        [i].publisher.first()
    }
    .sink { completion in
        print("Received Completion: \(completion)")
    } receiveValue: { v in
        print("Received Value: \(v)")
    }
```

My expectation is that the source publisher emits the values from 1 to 5 into the stream. Each number gets transformed into (just for the sake of it) a new publisher that emits exactly the first value and then completes. Since this is done with each number, I would expect that all values reach the sink. This is not the case, however. Output looks like this:

```
request unlimited
receive value: (1)
Received Value: 1
receive value: (2)
Received Value: 2
receive value: (4)
Received Value: 4
receive finished
Received Completion: finished
receive value: (3)
receive value: (5)
```

In fact, only 3 values reach the sink before the completion event arrives. Why is this? The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/flatmap(maxpublishers:_:)-3k7z5) states:

> successful completion of the new Publisher does not complete the overall stream.

Even more curious, when you replace `.flatMap()` for `.flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1))` and add a `.share()` to the original source publisher only the first value makes it to the sink.

Any pointers are much appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your use of `DispatchQueue.global()` is the problem. The `values.publisher` sends all of its outputs, and its completion, downstream to the `delay` operator as soon as `values.publisher` receives the subscription. The `delay` operator schedules six blocks (five for the output numbers and one for the completion) to run on `DispatchQueue.global()` 0.1 seconds later.

`DispatchQueue.global()` is a **concurrent** queue. This means that it can run any number of blocks simultaneously. So there is no guarantee which of the six scheduled blocks will finish first.

It is in general a bad idea to use a concurrent queue as a Combine scheduler. You should use a serial queue instead. Here's a simple example:

```
var cancel = values.publisher
    .delay(for: 0.1, scheduler: DispatchQueue(label: "my queue"))
    .print()
    .flatMap() { i in
        [i].publisher.first()
    }
    .sink { completion in
        print("Received Completion: \(completion)")
    } receiveValue: { v in
        print("Received Value: \(v)")
    }
```

But you probably want to create the queue once and store it in a property, so you can use it with multiple publishers.

If you actually want the outputs to be delivered on the main queue (perhaps because you're going to use them to update a view), you should just use `DispatchQueue.main`.

Comment: Nice catch. I was thinking it was because his cancellable was destructing.

Comment: So there's no need to create the dispatch queue separately beforehand? That code doesn't create five dispatch queues?

Comment: It creates one dispatch queue. It would only create five if `delay`'s `scheduler` argument were an `@autoclosure`.

Comment: But it would generally be wiser to create the dispatch queue beforehand and store in in a property for reuse.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Doesn't that feel like a total flaw in Combine? Is there even a way to get the behavior that I would expect: Process each of the pipelines for the values [1,2,3,4,5] in parallel and only after all "processing" blocks finished, send the completion signal?

Comment: Follow up: With the pointers given I read up on https://forums.swift.org/t/runloop-main-or-dispatchqueue-main-when-using-combine-scheduler/26635

So, from what I understand, what I want to do (process 1,2,3,4,5 in parallel but only afterwards complete) seems possible if I use `flatMap()` and have the publisher within `flatMap` `receiveOn` a concurrent queue. So that `flatMap` will ensure that it only completes after all concurrent pipelines complete, right?

Comment: That might work, if you don't care whether the order of the outputs is preserved.

Comment: Another follow up: If you add a `sleep(1)` to the `flatMap`, given your explanation, I would have expected the pipeline to complete immediately. Because all passed values are "held up" up by the sleep while the completion signal should (?) pass without delay, shouldn't it?